# Disable a specific ethernet card via batch commands on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, scripting, powershell, wmi

What I would like to do is disable a NIC based on the connection name (aka: what you see in the "network connections" window, or what you would use with netsh commands).

I know enabling/disabling can be done using devcon, however devcon identifies the device using the hardware ID of the physical NIC (e.g.: `PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8139&SUBSYS_813910EC&REV_10\4&282B82B8&0&08F0`), not the name of the connection associated with it (e.g.: "Local area connection 2").

So basically I need something to map the connection name to the hardware ID of the device as returned by:

```
devcon listclass Net
```

Then disabling can be done via devcon.

Any idea on how to do that ?
Any smarter/simpler way of doing that ?

Comment: Why not netsh?    .

Answer (score 3):

**XP** (Lan Wired)

Here, NetConnectionStatus=2 grabs the *active* (connected) network interface and 'more +1' skips the header line:

```
C:\>wmic.exe nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get PNPDeviceID |more +1
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8139&SUBSYS_813910EC&REV_10\4&1F7DBC9F&1&30F0
```

Then feeding the string (up to the first ampersand for short) to [devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) to disable and then enable the internet connection:

```
C:\>devcon.exe disable PCI\VEN_10EC
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8139&SUBSYS_813910EC&REV_10\4&1F7DBC9F&1&30F0: Disabled
1 device(s) disabled.

C:\>devcon.exe enable PCI\VEN_10EC
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8139&SUBSYS_813910EC&REV_10\4&1F7DBC9F&1&30F0: Enabled
1 device(s) enabled.
```

*wmic output is wide so with wordwrap off in Notepad if you take a look at 1.txt like this it is fairly clear:*

*`C:\>wmic.exe nic > 1.txt`*

*`C:\>1.txt`*

---

**Windows 7** Wifi Connection (another approach sans devcon.exe)

This worked for me:

```
C:\>wmic.exe nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get Index |more +1
12
C:\>wmic.exe path win32_networkadapter where index=12 call disable
C:\>wmic.exe path win32_networkadapter where index=12 call enable
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable the connection named Local Area Connection and hence its device:

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLE
```

To verify this:

```
netsh interface show interface
```

This will disable the network device which can be verified using device manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet, definatelly check this guy's [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860673/programatically-disable-enable-network-interface).

Comment: This is a good read - it's amazing how difficult this is, really.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start - using **wmic** will get you something you can feed to devcon,

```
wmic:root\cli>nic where(NetConnectionID="Local Area Connection") get PNPDeviceID
PNPDeviceID
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_10BD&SUBSYS_10FD1734&REV_02\3&33FD14CA&0&C8
```

So a shell script to find the **Device ID** of *Local Area Connection* would read,

```
wmic nic where(NetConnectionID="Local Area Connection") get PNPDeviceID | find "PCI\"
```

You can use devcon with partial matches of the device id, here's a command I used to disable the WLAN in 70 Asus Eee Box B203s,

```
devcon disable PCI\VEN_1814*DEV_0781
```

(the * is just instead of escaping the ampersand in the script)

Comment: This is probably even easier in Powershell, especially since you need the WMI query.